# How do i enable Genie effect (of mac os) in ubuntu 20.04 via compiz

Tags: 20.04, compiz, animations

I have compiz-gnome installed and set the settings for open,close and minimise animation to

`magic lamp`

`duration 350`

`window match:(type=Normal | Dialog | ModalDialog | Unknown)`

and moved up the settings to the top of the list as shown in the pic but no effect

[compiz animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsRNU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Gnome [Extension.](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3740/compiz-alike-magic-lamp-effect/) Worked for me like a charm.